# Convert initialised variables to declared variables

Tags: c++, fstream

I am restructuring my code and I have a long list of initialised variables:

```
int i = 3;
```

etc.

What is an easy way of converting this into a list of declarations? These would be:

```
int i;
```

etc.

Comment: What's the goal? Turning initialized variables into uninitialized variables?

Comment: `s/\([ \t]\) *\(\w+\) \(\w+\) = \w+;/\1\2 \3;/`---capture leading space, type, and name.

Comment: "What's the goal? Turning initialized variables into uninitialized variables?" -- Yes "s/\([ \t]\) *\(\w+\) \(\w+\) = \w+;/\1\2 \3;/" -- how do I use this?

Comment: Why do you want uninitialized variables ?

Comment: You want a tool to make your code worse? Yikes. Also if your code has that many variable declarations, I'd sort _that_ out first.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any tool for automated text-processing for this task. A particularly apt and well-known one is `sed`. Just pipe your source code through it:

```
sed -e 's/\(\s*\)\([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*\) \([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*\) =.*/\1\2 \3;/' code/src/*.{cc,cpp,c}
```

The regular expression above uses `[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]` to represent a C identifier. (Based on the consistency of your coding style, you may have to be more clever with some of the whitespace.)

Add the switch `-i` for an in-place replacement. This changes your file directory, so be careful.